# Group CSV file data to create report

Tags: powershell, object, report

I have a CSV file with below fields:

[image: Excel Table]

[image: Report2]

How can I create a report with the below fields?

```
$lookupDatafiltered = Import-Csv -Path .\lookups_shutdown.csv

$lookupDatafiltered | Group-Object Region, Country, Status | Select-Object @{n='Region';e={$_.Group[0].Region}}, @{n='Country';e={$_.Group[0].Country}},@{n='Status';e={$_.Group[0].Status}}, Count | Sort-Object -Property Region , Country | export-csv -Path "C:\change\Country.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

How to get the status count also to the exported csv per country

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have uploaded the image.  Please helo to click Table 1 and Report2.. Sorry for typo since im new to this site. Also i want simple group-object to get this report instead of pivot table

Comment: This does not look like a programming issue (which makes it off-topic for SO). [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might be a more appropriate place for it.

Comment: i want to generate the below report from powershell.the CSV value as attached

Comment: @Enigma SO is not a code writing service, provide us the code you've written already so we can help debug.

Comment: $lookupDatafiltered = Import-Csv -Path .\lookups_shutdown.csv $lookupDatafiltered | Group-Object Region, Country, Status | Select-Object @{n='Region';e={$_.Group[0].Region}}, @{n='Country';e={$_.Group[0].Country}},@{n='Status';e={$_.Group[0].Status}}, Count | Sort-Object -Property Region , Country | export-csv -Path "C:\change\Country.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: But im unable to get the status column count where how many systems are up and down per country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your given code snippet as an auxiliary result:

```
$lookupDatafiltered = Import-Csv -Path .\lookups_shutdown.csv
$lookupDataAux = $lookupDatafiltered | | Group-Object Region, Country, Status | 
    Select-Object @{n='Region' ;e={$_.Group[0].Region }}, 
                  @{n='Country';e={$_.Group[0].Country}},
                  @{n='Status' ;e={$_.Group[0].Status }}, 
                  Count | 
      Sort-Object -Property Region, Country, Status
$lookupDataAux  | Group-Object -Property Region,Country | 
    Select-Object @{n='Region' ;e={$_.Group[0].Region }}, 
                  @{n='Country';e={$_.Group[0].Country}},
                  @{n='up'     ;e={[int]($_.Group | ForEach-Object { if( $PSItem.Status -EQ 'up'   ) { $PSItem| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count }})}},
                  @{n='down'   ;e={[int]($_.Group | ForEach-Object { if( $PSItem.Status -EQ 'down' ) { $PSItem| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count }})}},
                  @{n='total'  ;e={($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Count -Sum).Sum}}  |
        export-csv -Path "C:\change\Country.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Please consider moving the `Sort-Object` cmdlet to the latter pipeline…

Comment: Thanks Josef.. much appreciated. That works perfect...much much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Theo. I have done this and i have accepted the answer.